# tensorflow is only available in virtual env in anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I installed tensorflow-gpu in anaconda3. 
The steps I followed are:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
source activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

After these steps, I find that if I use the python and ipython in `anaconda3/bin`, I can't import tensorflow (no module named tensorflow)
But If I activate the environment of tensorflow or I use the python and ipython in `anaconda3/env/tensorflow/bin`, I can import tensorflow.

And there is also no directory for tensorflow in`anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-package`

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a conda environment and installed Tensorflow to that environment. Therefore you can only use Tensorflow inside that environment.

If you wish to use Tensorflow outside of an environment then don't activate the environment you created and just pip install Tensorflow.